# Using SQL, How to "rename" integers with alphabetic values?

Tags: sql

I have a requirement where after joining a table I need the system to rename certain numeric values with their descriptions

For instance:

When I execute the following query:

select * from order_type and the results show as below:

| Order Name | order_Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 01/12/2021 |
| A2 | 1 | 01/12/2021 |
| B3 | 2 | 01/05/2021 |
| B5 | 1 | 01/04/2021 |
| C7 | 2 | 12/29/2020 |

Unfortunately the way the system is designed the order type has no descriptor. SO is there any way to say

Order_Type value '1' = Make.......
Order_Type Value '2' = Buy

so when someone runs the query again they see the below:

select * from order_type and the results show as below:

| Order Name | order_Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Make | 01/12/2021 |
| A2 | Make | 01/12/2021 |
| B3 | Buy | 01/05/2021 |
| B5 | Make | 01/04/2021 |
| C7 | Buy | 12/29/2020 |

Thank you

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: You could use a CASE expression (or equivalent in whatever SQL variant you are using). Or you could have an "orderTypeLookup" table with two columns, to map the numbers to their equivalent text, and then join your query to that - that would be the more flexible solution, if the list of order types could change, and/or if you need to do this in more than one query.

Comment: P.S. `order_type` seems like maybe the wrong name for your table? Is it not a list of individual orders? If so then just `orders` might be a more meaningful name. Give it some thought.

Comment: Thank you so much. As far as the table, yeah this is a custom system that was built a while back and I was supposed to be the BA guy. I guess cause of how terribly the system was built the "technical" person quit. SO I have to do all this crazy stuff

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select ot.*,
       (case when order_type = 1 then 'Make' 
             when order_type = 2 then 'Buy'
        end) as description
from order_type ot;
```

That said, you should have a reference table with this information so you can use a `join` with canonical names.  Defining this for each query that might need it is a recipe for data inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    OrderName,
    CASE order_Type WHEN 1 THEN 'Make' WHEN 2 THEN 'Buy' END AS order_Type,
    Date
FROM order_type;
```